# Place fixed aspect ratio objects in a varying aspect ratio container

Tags: html, css

Given a container div of unknown aspect ratio, I want to display one or two blocks of content with fixed 1:1 aspect ratios, like images or code listings. Here's an example setup:
https://jsfiddle.net/3vq0rxwj/2/

```
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content-object"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x350" /></div>
  <div class="content-object"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x350" /></div>
</div>
```

To use the available space best, for a container aspect ratio of between 2:3 and 3:2, a single object should be shown as large as possible. For an aspect ratio less than 2:3, the two objects should be shown above one another and for an aspect ratio greater than 3:2, they should be shown next to each other, again as large as possible.

Is there a way to get this to work without JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
.content-container {
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#9999FF;
  width:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 100px);
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.content-object {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:flex-start;
}

.content-object:nth-child(1) {
    flex:0 1 350px;
    background:Plum;
}


.content-object:nth-child(2) {
    flex:1 0 350px;
    background:Purple;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px)
{
    .content-object:nth-child(1) {
        flex:1 0 350px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:900px)
{
    .content-object:nth-child(1) {
        flex:1 0 350px;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmckay/3vq0rxwj/4/

Comment: This uses the widths of the objects and uses the screen width to determine the layout. The container div is not guaranteed to be as wide as the screen and the objects are not guaranteed to have a known width. They should be as large as possible, not exactly n by n pixels in size. So I'm looking for a solution that only depends on the aspect ratio of the elements.

Comment: @FlorianRhiem maybe you can replace the px widths with vw (viewport widths)